# AWS-SES open/click tracking

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services, email, email-validation

Is there a way to see if someone has open an email sent through AWS simple email service (as notification or from API)?

I tried using 'getSendStatistics' but it just shows delivered and bounced details...I have also tried using SNS and adding my 'Configuration Set' in the header but even with that I am getting notifications for Send and delivered mails and not the for open/clicked which is what I am looking for.

Hope you guys will be able to help, Thanks.

Re: Can anyone tell me why we need to specify 'domain' in Configuration Set when we are setting Event Type as 'click and open'.

Do I have to set it up somewhere before using it, as all the other events mention over here are working properly save click and open.
[Please refer the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sqly.jpg)

Comment: That's not how e-mail works. You'd need the receiver to opt-in to sending that information.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, SES [includes the ability to track open and click events](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/08/amazon-ses-introduces-open-and-click-metrics-for-tracking-customer-engagement/).

SNS allows you to handle each event as it happens, and you should be able to look in CloudWatch to see aggregate statistics.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried cloud watch after you recommend...but I am having the same problem over there i.e all other events are working but the open and click. which made me wonder that if I have to answer "Which domain do you want to use for open and click tracking?" differently.

Comment: We have been playing around with this very issue. Based on our findings so far, it absolutely has to do with "Which domain do you want to use for open and click tracking". AWS implies this is an optional field, we're finding it really isn't for open and click tracking.

Comment: @tejasvarsekar were you able to resolve?  we are looking to move from sendgrid to SES but we need click and opening callbacks, it looks like SES includes aggregate opens and clicks, but not singles.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, ensure your configuration is properly done. Here are the steps:

- Create a configuration set
- Add an SNS destination to the configuration set.
- Create an SNS topic for the destination. Create HTTP/HTTPS subscription for it and add the webhook the events will be sent to.

(I wrote a more detailed post with screenshots and examples [here](https://engage.so/blog/tracking-deliveries-opens-clicks-failures-and-complaints-for-amazon-ses/)).

Here are a few things to note:

- Ensure “Click” and “Open” are checked when setting the SNS destination
- Ensure you are sending/testing with HTML emails. Opens and clicks can only be tracked in HTML emails.
- The webhook URL has to be “confirmed” before SES sends events to it. SES will POST a `SubscribeURL` parameter to the URL. You are expected to visit the `SubscribeURL`  for verification.

Here is a short snippet of how I do it (NodeJS)

```
if (req.is('text/*')) {
  req.body = JSON.parse(req.body)
  if (req.body.SubscribeURL) {
    await got(req.body.SubscribeURL)
    return res.end()
  }
}
```

**Why do you need to specify a domain?**

The way clicks tracking works is that AWS rewrites the links in the emails with a link they can track and then redirect to the original link. By default, AWS uses rewrites the links with its own domain (awstrack.me). This means, a link like this `<a href=“https://awesome.site”>Visit</a>` will become something like `<a href=“https://random.us-east-1.awstrack.me/L0/encoded-url”>Visit</a>`. By specifying your own domain, you are able to use your own domain for rewriting instead of the default awstrack.me. (Some ESPs like Mailgun do not offer default and require you to setup your custom domain for click tracking).

Answer (score 0):

We can set SNS topic to get notification to email . While setting configuration set click all the options available (open,click,send...) and tag to message tag and destination to cloudwatch . Then you can see the logs in cloudwatch logs.  I have tried it . Got logs in cloudwatch and also notification to email.